# How can I disable 'Use default Gateway for remote networks' setting in Windows 10?

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-10

I have been disabling the 'use default gateway for remote networks' option to bypass unnecessary traffic from going through vpn. But after upgrading to Windows 10 I can't change the setting since the IPv4 Properties does not open up when I click it.

[image]

Is there any other way to access this setting?

Comment: If the IPv4 properties don't open, then I'd say you probably have a bigger problem that you should be concerned about first.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 well, he isn't alone with that problem. I have a fresh Windows 10 Installation here and the Properties button does nothing. There a number of TechNet Topics but so far, silence from Microsoft.

Comment: This was a bug. It was fixed in TH2. See related answer [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/949306/windows-10-windows-vpn-ipv4-properties-not-accessible/979698#979698)

Comment: How did you even get to this dialog box in Windows 10? I can't find anything like this in the current version of Windows.

Comment: @JonathanWood Easiest way is to go to Control Panel-> Network and Internet-> Network and Sharing Center-> Change Adapter Settings (on left)-> Right click any adapter and select properties. You will see a dialog like this open up with Networking Tab on it.

Comment: Some VPN profiles don't have the networking tab.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use this powershell command to enable/disable default gateway on VPN:

```
Set-VpnConnection -Name "myVPN" -SplitTunneling $True
```

Comment: Tried earlier, but my tracert goes always through VPN, even after applying this command. And yes, I know name of "myVPN". :(

Comment: what if I am using VPN Client called 'FortiClient' ? I can't list or set config using this above command. What is the solution for that.

Comment: Something is missing here. What does `True` mean? Do, or do not, use the remote default gateway?

Comment: $True mean this setting will be enabled, default value in windows is $False

Comment: I tried this, and it resulted in no traffic going through the VPN at all, not even the VPN-only sites -.-

Answer (score 9):

If you go to here: `%appdata%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk` open with text editor and for every Vpn connection listed change `IpPrioritizeRemote=1` – change this to `0` to disable

Comment: Nice, the tool is cool when run from `win+r` by `rasphone`.

Comment: Great answer. But now I found that the VPN I'm using automatically changes this back to 1 when connecting. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

source: https://windowsreport.com/vpn-split-tunneling-windows-10/

try one of:

1. Edit the VPN connection properties
   [image]
2. Use PowerShell

   ```
   Set-VPNconnection -name "Your VPN connection" -SplitTunneling $true
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Are these 'either-or', or 'both-and'?  (Number 2 on its own looks equivalent to the accepted answer.)

Comment: @mwfearnley either-or