# Editing VPN gateway properties in Windows 10

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-10, gateway

When setting up a VPN under Windows 10, I can't edit the properties for IPv4 Networking settings. Clicking on the "Properties" button, under the "Networking" tab of VPN Properties doesn't do anything.

I want to **disable the default gateway** just as you could in Windows 7 & 8. Is it a bug or do you disable it somewhere else? Or you can't you disable it (which is an absolute pain since it slows the connection horrendously)?

[image]

Comment: Wow, you're right. Clicking "Properties" does **absolutely nothing**. Very strange.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable 'Use default Gateway for remote networks' setting in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/954801/how-can-i-disable-use-default-gateway-for-remote-networks-setting-in-windows-1)

Comment: The non-working "Properties"-button was a bug. It has been [fixed in TH2](http://superuser.com/a/979698/389368).

Answer (score 0):

If you go to here:
%appdata%\roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk
open with text editor and for every Vpn connection listed change 
IpPrioritizeRemote=1 – change this to 0 to disable

Chris