# Share internet without vpn interferance

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares

So i have a 64 windows 10 machine

And i am sharing my internet with my roommate ,When i share the adapter named "Celular" everything works find until i connect to a VPN ,then my roommate don't receive the internet until i share with him from the new adapter created by the vpn  "Ethernet"

This is an image of the adapters:

[image: Image of the adapters]

How can i keep sharing "Celular" internet no matter if i connected to the vpn or not

I am really not sure if this is the best title so if someone else can be kind enough to suggest and edit for it that will be nice

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] This answer assumed that the built-in Windows VPN client was used. However, it turned out in the comments below that the OP is using a 3rd party VPN client, presumably OpenVPN-based going by the "TAP-Windows Adapter v9" name. That adapter does not expose the `use default gateway on remote network` setting in its property pages, so the following does not apply in this case (though it still attempts to answer the question as originally posted).

---

Make sure you the VPN connector is *not* set to provide Internet access via the remote machine.

Step by step:

- open Control Panel
- open Network and Sharing
- click Change adapter settings
- select the VPN adapter, right click and select Properties
- switch to the Networking tab

For each of the IPv4 and IPv6 protocols do the following:

- highlight then click Properties
- click Advanced
- uncheck Use default gateway on remote network

OK and close everything, then re-connect the VPN.

Comment: I am sorry,But my computer is in french ,it was kind of hard to follow your steps ,i didn't find the networking tab ,but tell me if this is what you mean http://i.stack.imgur.com/hl3hk.jpg , if yes i couldn't find  "Use default gateway on remote network" if no,please provide me with an image

Comment: @doitforthehairs You are one step away. Click the Avancé button, then Use default gateway on remote network should be the topmost checkbox.

Comment: i couldn't find it http://i.stack.imgur.com/xQmBb.jpg

Comment: You are looking at the wrong network adapter, "Ethernet 2" sounds like a wired network. You need to change the properties of the VPN adapter. In that case the IPv4 Avancé dialog would look something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/T2oR2.gif

Comment: but this is the adapter created by the vpn software (finchvpn) 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/B08yN.jpg
there is also ethernet3 created by speedify and vpn client created by softether vpn,I went through them all and none of them had that option,i tried this solution http://superuser.com/questions/954801/how-can-i-disable-use-default-gateway-for-remote-networks-setting-in-windows-1

both of the answers didn't work for me

Comment: The answer I posted assumed you used the built-in Windows VPN client, which does in fact create a VPN adapter for each connection, and that adapter has the option to `use default gateway on remote network` or not. Sorry, I don't know how this works for your VPN clients who appear to set up their own adapters rather than use the built-in ones.