# Windows 10 split tunneling

Tags: vpn, windows-10

I have 2 wifi connections, one has internet and the other doesn't. I use the one that has no internet to access local machines. When I connect via VPN, even the one that has no internet connection is being routed through the vpn. Is there a workaround for this. Basically, i want my local access to bypass the VPN.

Comment: Please check http://superuser.com/questions/949306/windows-10-windows-vpn-ipv4-properties-not-accessible, it seems it is the same problem.

Comment: @AntoineL is correct, you need to turn on split tunnelling

Answer (score 2):

They answered the question, but not fully.  Once you've created the VPN tunnel, use Powershell to set the tunnel.  In my example below, the connection is called "office."

To turn on split tunnel (what you're looking for):

```
set-vpnconnection office -splittunneling $True
```

If you decide to turn it off for some reason:

```
set-vpnconnection office -splittunneling $False
```

To view information about the tunnel:

```
get-vpnconnection office
```

To view info about *all* your tunnels:

```
get-vpnconnection
```