# Windows 10 PowerShell setting up split tunneling

Tags: windows-10, powershell, tunnel

I am trying to enable split tunneling on my laptop (Windows 10), I learned one has to use PowerShell to do it in Windows 10:

[Windows 10 split tunneling](https://superuser.com/questions/963922/windows-10-split-tunneling)

But when I type that command:

set-vpnconnection office -splittunneling $True

I get an error message:

A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'vpnconnection'.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you have to import a module not already loaded to Powershell. In your case, it's called `VpnClient`. So in Powershell type this and press enter:

```
import-module vpnclient
```

Now you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks @AmirHossein, it was actually a syntax error on my behalf...

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a space between Set and -VpnConnection:

Set -VpnConnection   [incorrect]

instead of:

Set-VpnConnection    [correct]

Once syntax fixed, all worked (after restarting the VPN connectoin).

Apologies if I wasted anyone's time.