# Windows 11 DNS resolution not working with any VPN service

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, windows-11

I have a Lenovo laptop with Windows 11 installed. Wifi and ethernet work fine but from some time I am not able to use any VPN service anymore, I use Forti VPN and Keepsoft VPN unlimited services. When I connect to them everything on the computer isn't able to resolve the DNS names.

Other than the VPNs, Wifi, and ethernet, I have VMWare networks and Twingate adapters. Plus I have wsl and android subsystems active if they could cause something. I use as antivirus and firewall the system defaults but I also tried to change them with nod32.

I tried to set Cloudflare DNS on everything, remove them, tried everything written here [Windows 10 DNS resolution via VPN connection not working](https://superuser.com/q/966832/946851), uninstall and reinstall the VPNs, and these commands

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
```

but it is no use. I really need to resolve this and I can't format everything otherwise I would have already done it. I am afraid to uninstall the wireless adapter because maybe then I am not able to install it anymore and I will have just an expensive brick for a month.

So here the requested configs:

without VPN

ipconfig: https://pastebin.com/BwJJbq4p

routes: https://pastebin.com/t2YAu3Qc

nslookup:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  100.95.0.251

Nome:    superuser.com
Addresses:  151.101.65.69
      151.101.129.69
      151.101.1.69
      151.101.193.69
```

with forti VPN:

ipconfig: https://pastebin.com/6DiudDRQ

routes: https://pastebin.com/dHFW2eYq

nslookup:

```
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  157.138.1.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
```

Comment: show us ipconfig /all both with and without the VPN software running. do not obscure the DNS server addresses in the output. also include `route print` and `nslookup superuser.com` both with and without.

Comment: @FrankThomas I added them all in the main post

Comment: so 157.138.1.8 does appear to be a DNS server, and I am able to query it and get a valid response via nslookup. Your network layout seems more complex than I'd typically expect. do you know why you have routes to 157.238.x.y when the vpn is not engaged? I mean, they aren't a full match for the DNS servers IP. but somthing seems off there.

Comment: @FrankThomas yes, the two 157.138.24.x are two computers I connect at my university in their internal LAN

Comment: so are you using a VPN service (like a consumer privacy service) or a VPN client to connect to your university VPN? It looks like the DNS failure occurs when you try to access the university DNS server (157.138.1.8).

Comment: I am using a VPN client called Forti by Fortinet, the version is provided by my university. But still, even with another VPN client the DNS resolution doesn't work

Comment: So I'm going to recommend that you reach out to your universities IT. Its likely that the issue is one of their firewalls. Your routes look good for on-VPN to reach the university's DNS server, and the server itself is up and responding to the public internet. that you can't reach it when VPN'd into their network, sure looks like an issue on their end, and less likely yours.

Comment: @FrankThomas but I have the issue with every VPN, not only with the one of my university as I wrote in the main post. 3 different VPNs have the same problem with only my accounts? I likely doubt that, I am still convinced that there is something wrong with my Windows instance. Even so, with another computer I am able to use them

Comment: If there was a method to completely reset all the networking services without formatting I think that the VPNs will start working again